# Excluding Records using specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, data-cleaning

I have a table as below

| ID | Type | Part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CD1 | Service | A |
| CD1 | Service | null |
| CD1 | Service | B |
| CD1 | Sales | A |
| CD2 | Service | null |
| CD2 | Sales | B |
| CD3 | Service | A |
| CD3 | Service | null |

Output Required:

| ID | Type | Part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CD1 | Service | A |
| CD1 | Service | B |
| CD1 | Sales | A |
| CD2 | Service | null |
| CD2 | Sales | B |
| CD3 | Service | A |

Explanation : For example CD1 has Service as Type with A,B and a null as Part, CD2 has Service as Type with only null as Part. Since CD1 has A,B as part, null value record has to be excluded and CD2 with Service as Type doesn't contain any values other than null it should not be excluded.

Similarly CD3 has Service as Type with A and null as Part. Since A exists null value record has to be excluded.

Is this possible to achieve using SQL?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why are there two `CD1` records in the output but only one `CD3` record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a ranking using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, where the null values will be assigned the least value. Then you can select all rows from your table where the value is not null or the ranking is 1 (if null is found in first position, it will mean that it's the only value for that combination of ID and Type):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Type 
                             ORDER     BY Part DESC) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT ID,
       Type, 
       Part
FROM cte
WHERE Part IS NOT NULL 
   OR rn = 1
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/etvoZqFHiED5LLA3gxcpZs/2).

Comment: In some cases for an ID and Type, There might be more than one part. Like for example CD1 might have Part A,B and null for Service. In this case how to exclude null value record?

Comment: Check the link posted in the bottom of the answer: this solution addresses your issue. @user12490809

Comment: Only if a ID against Type having a single Part. But if the ID against Type is having more than 1 like A,B and null value the output would be B. But I require A and B. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably it's possible @user12490809. Please update your post with this side case in order to make the situation clear to all readers.

Comment: Updated, Pls Check

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Does it work for you? @user12490809